# Crystal Reports issue with dataset

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, dataset

I have a dataset in visual studio 2005 that uses a stored procedure as its data source.  I am able to preview the data by right-clicking on the dataset and I see the expected data.  In my Crystal Report, which uses this same dataset as its data source, I have reverified the database and I see the new column displayed as an option for me to use in my report.  I drag this new field into the Details section and when I run the report I do not see any data for that specific new column.

Any ideas why?

Comment: If you have any code to share, please do so!

Comment: check if the newly added column is being properly filled in the dataset or not. put the breakpoint before the line of code where crystal report is being attached to the dataset and watch the dataset.

Comment: Thanks Ali, as I stated I was able to preview the data in the dataset.  There is no code really to display.  The report has a data source that is configured properly, there is no criteria in the selection expert, I am just not getting data displayed in the report itself ONLY for the new columns.  There was an old dataset that I renamed and created a new one as the datasource with the newer columns.